# How to, given a 2D numpy arrayMatrix that contains "triplets" of RGB values generate an image?

Tags: python, image, python-2.7, numpy

You see, most of the posts that discuss image creation deal with a 3D Matrix[0][1][2] that effectively contains the necessary info to apply directly

```
img = Image.fromarray(Matrix, 'RGB')
```

However, I'm stuck with a massive matrix that has "3n" columns and "n" rows. As you might see, the "image" is coded in a fashion reminding me of P3/P6 formats:

```
[ 0 0 0 255 255 255 0 0 0
  0 0 0 255 255 255 0 0 0 
  255 255 255 0 0 0 255 255 255]
```

The above 2D matrix represents 3x3 "pixels", and using Image.fromarray produces an image full of holes. I've thinking of splitting it into three (!!!) 2 dimensional arrays and then using **np.dstack** but that sounds **terribly** inefficient as the code is dinamically generating thousands of matrices with large dimensions (700x2100) that need to be presented as images.

This is what I'm thinking of doing, btw:

```
R = np.zeros((Y, X), dtype = np.uint8) # Same for G & B
    for Row in range(Y):
        for Column in range(3*X):
            if Column % 3 == 0: # With Column-1 for G and -2 for B
                R[Row][Column/3] = 2DMatrix[Row][Column]
#After populating R, G, B
RGB0 = np.dstack([R, G, B])
img = Image.fromarray(RGB0, 'RGB')
```

Thanks!

Comment: Given a 2D Matrix w/ the discussed characteristics (Y x 3X) and an image that'll have (Y, X) expected pixels,
    `R = np.zeros((Y, X), dtype = np.uint8) # Same for G & B
     for Row in range(Y):
         for Column in range(3*X):
             if Column % 3 == 0: # With Column-1 for G and -2 for B
                 R[Row][Column/3] = 2DMatrix[Row][Column]
     #After populating R, G, B
     RGB = np.dstack([R, G, B])
     img = Image.fromarray(RGB, 'RGB')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`numpy.reshape`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html) should work for this.  It's also important that the color values are 8-bit unsigned:

```
>>> import numpy as np

>>> a = [[0, 0, 0, 255, 255, 255, 0, 0, 0],
...      [0, 0, 0, 255, 255, 255, 0, 0, 0],
...      [255, 255, 255, 0, 0, 0, 255, 255, 255]]
>>> a = np.array(a)
>>> a.astype('u1').reshape((3,3,3))

array([[[  0,   0,   0],
        [255, 255, 255],
        [  0,   0,   0]],

       [[  0,   0,   0],
        [255, 255, 255],
        [  0,   0,   0]],

       [[255, 255, 255],
        [  0,   0,   0],
        [255, 255, 255]]], dtype=uint8)

>>> import PIL.Image
>>> i = PIL.Image.fromarray(a.astype('u1').reshape((3,3,3)), 'RGB')
```

This seems to work the way we would expect:

```
>>> i.size
(3, 3)
>>> i.getpixel((0,0))
(0, 0, 0)
>>> i.getpixel((1,0))
(255, 255, 255)
>>> i.getpixel((2,0))
(0, 0, 0)
>>> i.getpixel((0,1))
(0, 0, 0)
>>> i.getpixel((1,1))
(255, 255, 255)
>>> i.getpixel((2,1))
(0, 0, 0)
>>> i.getpixel((0,2))
(255, 255, 255)
>>> i.getpixel((1,2))
(0, 0, 0)
>>> i.getpixel((2,2))
(255, 255, 255)
```

Comment: Thank you! This seems to work like a charm. Just one thing: for an image of X rows and Y columns, should I reshape as `.reshape(Y, X, 3) `, right? Because it then seems weird that the convention for displaying pixels and arrays is exactly the opposite when using  `i.getpixel `.

Cheers,

Comment: Yes, `reshape((Y, X, 3))` should do what you want.